# How can I make youtube video fit the screen?

Tags: html, youtube-iframe-api

I am loading a youtube video using an iFrame. With the current code the video's margins are slightly cropped (thumbnail image included). What do I have to change in order to make it fit the screen with black background beneath? To test just paste this code in an html file and run it in browser. Window resize shows the issue.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Youtube Video</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'/>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor='white' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0'>
        <!-- The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
        <div id='player'></div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    playerVars: { 'iv_load_policy': 3, 'controls': 1, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0, 'fs': 0 },
                    frameborder: '0',
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: 'axZ1e0_2ysc',
                    events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });
            }

            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                document.title = '0';
            }

            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                    document.title = '1';
                } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED || event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
                    document.title = '2';
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS to your site to make body of your page 100% of the viewport:

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXpmWR

Or you can use CSS to set the widht and height of the `iframe` element:

```
iframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRjWWb